# If $A, B$ are conditionally independent by $C$ prove that $P(A|B,C) = P(A|C)$

Tags: probability

Also $P(B,C) \ne 0$

I tried using bayes theorem and the definition of conditional independence but I got nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of conditional independence of A and B by C is (according to wikipedia) $P(A,B|C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)$

Using conditional probability, rewrite the LHS as $\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(C)}$

then bring the $P(C)$ up to the RHS and note that $P(B|C)P(C)=P(B,C)$, so now we have

$P(A,B,C) = P(A|C)P(B,C)$

next divide both sides by $P(B,C)$ (hence necessity for $P(B,C)\neq 0$) to obtain

$P(A|B,C)=P(A|C)$

as required. I would regard this to be an equally valid definition of conditional independence.